# How to check if a WP_Query has data

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have the following WP_Query, which works great:

```
<h4>Frequently Asked Questions</h4>

<ul class="faq">

<?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'questions',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',                                        
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'types',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'customer-service'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there's a title on the top of the query and I would like to find a way to only show that title if there are values inside the query. If not, in case there are no questions, the title still shows and it looks weird.

Any ideas how can I check if there are values inside a query or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it up a bit and use have_posts method to check if there are any results:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'questions',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',                                        
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'types',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'customer-service'
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($loop->have_posts()){
?>
<h4>Frequently Asked Questions</h4>

<ul class="faq">
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php }
```